# passing arguments on aws Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

have anyone had any experience with Data Pipeline?

I have been trying to find out if there is a way to pass arguments between activities in a Pipeline. unfortunately aws documentation is not very helpful on these issues...
lets say i have a ShellCommandActivity and an EmrActivity.
i would like to get a string from my ShellCommandActivity that i can use later as an argument for my EmrActivity (lets say a file name or an s3 path) 
or maybe for other objects in the pipeline - for example a DataNode

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have similar problem to tackle any other solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to acheive this would be to let the shell script write the string to some file in S3.  In EMR activity read the file.  Also add the EMR activity depends on ShellCommandActivity

Comment: thank you for your answer. the solution we found in the end was not to use aws data-pipeline. it was more simple to roll our own...